# Register opening and closing android app

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

How can I register when the user open and close my app? I want to register every opening and every closing.

Lifecycle methods for example onResume() are not effective because the app use multiple activitys.

I can't find anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to check if the app is exited or run is like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

public static final String LOG_TAG = "MyApp";

public boolean wasInBackground = true;

private AppSession appSession;
private Timer mActivityTransitionTimer;
private TimerTask mActivityTransitionTimerTask;
private final long MAX_ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_TIME_MS = 2000;  // Time allowed for transitions

Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks activityCallbacks = new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        if (wasInBackground) {
            //Do app-wide came-here-from-background code
            appEntered();
        }
        stopActivityTransitionTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        startActivityTransitionTimer();
    }

    ...

};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(activityCallbacks);
}

public void startActivityTransitionTimer() {
    this.mActivityTransitionTimer = new Timer();
    this.mActivityTransitionTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // Task is run when app is exited
            wasInBackground = true;
            appExited();
        }
    };

    this.mActivityTransitionTimer.schedule(mActivityTransitionTimerTask,
            MAX_ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_TIME_MS);
}

public void stopActivityTransitionTimer() {
    if (this.mActivityTransitionTimerTask != null) {
        this.mActivityTransitionTimerTask.cancel();
    }

    if (this.mActivityTransitionTimer != null) {
        this.mActivityTransitionTimer.cancel();
    }

    this.wasInBackground = false;
}

private void appEntered() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "APP ENTERED");

    appSession = new AppSession();
}

private void appExited() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "APP EXITED");

    appSession.finishAppSession();

    // Submit AppSession to server
    submitAppSession(appSession);
    long sessionLength = (appSession.getT_close() - appSession.getT_open())/1000L;
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Session Length: " + sessionLength);
}
```

Comment: Amazing code! Thank you for sharing this elegant solution!

Comment: glad to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The onCreate method for the application class only runs once when the application is started. Maybe extend the application class and create some logic?

Or if you just record the application opening in the onCreate method of your first activity?

Comment: Thank you! A logic for the application class is really difficult. It wouldn't be a simple solution. I'm amazed that android doesn't give a simple solution for that. For example in iOS there are two delegate methods for that. The problem by your second solution is when the user left my app in another activity and open the app again my first activity onCreate() will not call. Is there a solution in android to restart application on every opening?